# Replace text that appears at the end of a string

Tags: r, string, replace

Consider `"artikelnr"`. I want to replace `"nr"` by `"nummer"`, but when I consider `"inrichting"`, I do NOT want to replace `"nr"`. So I just want to replace `"nr"` by `"nummer"` if it's at the end of a word.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`regex` is your friend, here:

```
sub('nr$', 'nummer', 'artikelnr')
# [1] "artikelnummer"
```

The `$` indicates "end of string", so `nr` will only be replaced with `nummer` when it appears at the end of the string.

`sub` can operate on an entire vector, e.g. for a character vector `x`, do:

```
sub('nr$', 'nummer', x)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using the `stringr` package, str_replace is also handy :

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("artikelnr", "nr$", "nummer")
```